# elasticsearch highlight java api client - show highlight when searchresponse from elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have code search from elasticsearch with index is : **news** and have a field is **topic_highlight**. I want field is **topic_highlight** containers in **highlight** when elasticsearch response result.
Below my code:

```
SearchResponse res = client.prepareSearch("news").setVersion(true)
.addHighlightedField("topic_highlight")
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("status",1))
.setHighlighterFragmentSize(2000)
.setHighlighterNumOfFragments(1)
.addSort("modified_date",SortOrder.DESC).setSize(50).setFrom(from)
.execute().actionGet();
```

I know why? this code return field higlight {}.

Any nobody know, please help me !
Thanks you !

Answer (score 1):

Please, look, here you can find highlighted fields

[image: screenshot]

Use this way:

```
res.hits().getAt(i).highlightFields()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a minute to read through [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) - this looks helpful but it would benefit from some explanation of what the code does, consider [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41385887/edit)-ing that in?